# How to pass and convert Array objects from swift/objective-c to C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift

I have array of objects named photoArray and it has property date and index. I can access that like photoArray[arrayIndex].index / photoArray[index].date.
I am C++ developer so i code all my logics in c++. I want to pass this objects from Swift to c++ . I have created C++ class and its header . Then I  have then created C++ wrapper class in objective- c and its header with definition. Also created the bridging header. 

My question - What shall be the code snippet in my CPP-wrapper.mm just like I have done with string. Also What should be the data  type in my CPP.cpp class?

My goal is to print this photoArray from c++. Let me know if it is possible to do so or any clarification needed.  
ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit  
class ViewController: UIViewController {  

override func viewDidLoad() {  
    super.viewDidLoad()  

    let world = " passed as string"  
    CPP_Wrapper().hello_cpp_wrapped(world)  
    getPhotos()  

func getPhotos() {  
     let photoLibraryAccess = PhotoLibraryAccess();  
     photoLibraryAccess.authenticate {   
     let photoArray = photoLibraryAccess.getPhotos()    
     CPP_Wrapper().eventclassification_cpp_wrapped(photoArray) // pass to c++} }}
```

CPP.cpp

```
void CPP::hello_cpp(const std::string& name) {
          cout << "Hello " << name << " in C++" << endl; }
void CPP::event_classification(const int * objectArray){
//        instead of int it should be name of class ?
          cout<<objectArray[1];   }
```

CPP-Wrapper.mm

```
 @implementation CPP_Wrapper
-  (void)hello_cpp_wrapped:(NSString *)name {
      CPP cpp;
      cpp.hello_cpp([name cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);}

- (void)event_classification_cpp_wrapped:(NSArray *)eventArray {
      CPP cpp;
      cpp.hello_cpp() // what should be the conversion code?    }
  @end
```

PhotoLibraryAccess.h

```
 @interface PhotoIndexDate : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger index;
    @property (nonatomic, copy, nonnull) NSString * date;
@end

@interface PhotoLibraryAccess : NSObject
     - (void)authenticate:(void ( ^ _Nonnull )())completion;
     - (nonnull NSArray <PhotoIndexDate *> *)getPhotos;
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that your photo type, `PhotoIndexDate`, is an Objective-C type that cannot be used in C or C++.  Here are some options you've got:

- Use a C struct to hold info about a photo.  The struct can be used in
  Swift, Objective-C, and C++.  Using an array of these structures in Swift may be a little tricky, though.
- Use `NSArray <PhotoIndexDate    *>` to store the photos like you do
  now, but build a C array of C/C++ objects from it in
  `event_classification_cpp_wrapped` and send it to    a C++
  classification method.
- Similar to the previous option, but    instead of building an array
  of C/C++ objects and sending it to C++,    iterate through the array,
  build a C/C++ photo object from it and    send it to C++ one at a
  time.

Which option you choose depends on a few things, such as:

- Do you want to make changes to the photo array in C++ such that the
  changes are visible back in Objective-C or Swift code?
- Do you mind creating a copy of the whole Swift/Objective-C array in
  C++?  Is it OK from memory usage perspective?

Comment: Thanks @OmniProg. It works. I have created Class eventObject in CPP.cpp holding array of date and index. Then created the class instance to store the photoArray from CPP-Wrapper